# What's the best way to solo elites?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm playing a Powertech spec'd bounty hunter which is currently at level 13.  My problem lies in the fact that whenever elites enemies close, my guy drops immediately (3 or four hits max).  And not elites at the same level either, so far even four levels below me are downing me if they get close.  I don't have a lot experience with MMOs, never been interested in WOW.  SO basically, what do I need to do to make my bounty hunter a survivable class? I get so very tired of waiting on the med bot to respawn.

Comment: Just to make sure, you do use your companion, right?

Comment: How many people are you doing the heroic with? As many as the mission recommends? Heroics are not designed to be soloable, not even a few levels above their difficulty.

Comment: I think sarge actually means Strong and Elite enemies, not Heroic missions. And they appear normally in non-heroic areas.

Comment: @svick yeah i'm using mako as a healer (using the med scan ability).

Comment: The enemies that show up with the gold around them when you target them on the action bar.

Comment: Maybe being meleed is the problem, I woukd have expected bouty hunters to do well only in ranged combat.  Though I have no evidence to support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a Powertech in beta and now play a Vanguard (Trooper equivalent). At your level, this is how I'd recommend taking on an Elite enemy:

1. Make sure you're at full health and are using your Combustible Gas Cylinder (CGC)
2. Start at range with Unload
3. If CGC proc'd and Rail Shot is available, use it while running towards the enemy. Rail shot will always be your highest priority ability, so use it whenever it's available.
4. Use Explosive Dart
5. Use Rocket Punch as soon as you're in melee range
6. Use Rapid Shots when your heat is around 50% to allow it to regenerate.
7. Use your Electro Dart now to stun the enemy for a few.
8. Stick to Rail Shot, Explosive Dart, and Rocket Punch while in melee range at this level.

My final tip is to make sure you're always doing something! Don't waste global cooldowns trying to figure out what to do next; get used to your abilities and see what's available and what isn't.

Comment: Power Shot is a Mercenary-only ability. This approach works just fine. The whole point is to keep your heat below 60 and if it breaches that, vent heat.

Comment: I stand corrected on Power Shot. I've removed my incorrect comment.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing anything about your character, it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong. But, based on my experience, killing single Elite (gold) enemy should be straight-forward.

I haven't played Bounty Hunter, so here's some of my general guesses of why does that happen to you:

1. You don't have the correct abilities, or you didn't level them. You should visit your class trainer periodically to purchase new abilities and upgrade old ones.
2. You don't use the correct abilities. Have a look at all your abilities. Are there some that could help you significantly?
3. You (or your companion) don't have the correct gear. I don't think this isn't very likely, since mission rewards should give you gear that's good enough.

Comment: +1 Great answer to a poorly worded and/or researched question.

Comment: All my abilities are leveled all the way up... my gear is the standard heavy armor that requires at least level 13... the level that I am.  My abilities are great at mowing though people, but I specialized in the tank side of the class and I have the heavy armor ability. My abilities seemed designed to draw whole groups to me, which I do with regular groups but even one elite gets to me and >4 seconds, waiting on the medical droid. It's my understanding that a tank, you know, is a tank... and can take a beating.

Comment: @mufasa sorry, If I knew enough to ask the question well, I probably wouldn't have had to ask some experts. Feel free to edit it up to your standards.

Comment: @sarge_smith: I understand. But it is difficult for us to help because it could be one of many, many different issues. Your spec, abilities you've tried; level of opponent vs. you; companion usage; more context, or things you've tried; less bombastic statements like "drops immediately"; Etc.

Comment: @mufasa ask away... I am willing to answer any and all questions.  For comparisions sake, I do have a jedi knight that is level 12 that I can take out an elite with of the same level, he stands up to damage way better than my bounty hunter, even though he is the straight DPS version of the build.

Comment: @sarge_smith: Okay: "Your spec, abilities you've tried; level of opponent vs. you; companion usage; more context, or things you've tried." Your equipment. Order of spell usage. Heat levels.

Comment: spec=power tech, all bounty hunter abilities at full raise, skill points spent= upgrading rail loader to bypass 60% of armor, flame blast lv 2. Level of oponent=varies, most range between ten and 12 on drommand kas, the world I am currently on, particularry the mandalorians that lie between the spaceport and the imperial capital. Equipment = the base vender sold level thirteen gear... four pieces of such, I can give you total armor when I get home. Nothing any other vender sells I can wear on Drommand or the fleet.  Was using the great hunt blaster modified to full level to be useable.

Comment: @sarge_smith, you buy most of your equipment from vendors? Why don't you use equipment from quest rewards?

Comment: normal ability usage- death from above for two or three hits of 147 to 187, followed by explosive dart, then flurry of bolts, followed by either electro bolt or missile or rocket punch, depending on whether or not enimies close or stay at distance or if there is only one left. then I normally blow flamethrower in they are on top of me, at which point I am dead. That dead is vs a level ten elite, vs a level 12 I die before the electro dart part of the chain. Note that I am starting fights at as close to the full thirty meters as I can to buy myself time.

Comment: I upgraded to the best I could buy because I thought that my equipment was at fault so I switched it out to see... made no noticable diffrence.

Comment: heat levels haven't been a huge factor, because by the time they max out... I'm laying on the ground, they are high after the flame thrower, and require a vent heat.

Comment: @sarge_smith That area is an heroic-4 area! Each pull will have at least two elite and a strong mob, and are designed to be handled by a full group. No wonder you die fast. My advice: listen to the guards and don't go past the guard post. Instead, hop on a shuttle to Kaas City, and explore the other parts of the planet.

Comment: @sjoerd yeah, figured it out as I played yesterday... just my unfamiliarity with the game and not knowing where to find the information that I needed to know... also found out that the companion I thought was healing me didn't have her higher level abilities active...

Answer (score 1):

I play a bounty hunter as well, but do not recognize the problem you describe.

Some elites have **special abilities**. If you see a cross being painted on the ground you stand on **MOVE OUT**. Break off whatever ability you are using, and move away. The elite is throwing a granate (or calling in an air strike), and it will hit the cross very soon, and you don't want to be in that spot anymore when it does.

If you don't, you will die very quickly, as those special abilities hit hard.

Comment: perhaps I need to be dodging more... those attacks don't just follow you? Most of the ones I've seen seem to, but I have been afraid to run around too much for fear of triggering even more guys to kill.

Comment: no you don't want to run unless it's to either a) get in melee range or b) a ground based attack is being cast (you'll see a marker on the ground near you). b) is what he was referring to

Comment: @sjoerd I wanted to say thank you because this answer helped me huge even though corey d's was a little more complete.

Answer (score 1):

From one of OP's comments about Dromund Kaas:

> [..] particularry the mandalorians that lie between the spaceport and
>   the imperial capital.

That area is an Heroic-4 area! Each pull will have at least two elite and a strong mob, and are designed to be handled by a full group.

No wonder you die fast.

As a level 20 Bounty Hunter, about to leave the planet, I tried to clear up all my quests by soloing the heroic quests. I gave up on that goal, as even as a level 20 BH, I couldn't solo those groups reliablely.

So: **it is not your fault!** Those mobs are designed not to be soloable at your level.

Answer (score 0):

As a bounty hunter, your 1st companion is Mako, she's a healer. **Use her** (not the ship's droid). 
Elites are hard but doable (though at around 30 in Alderaan they do become harder). I'm not sure if you have stances like Sith Warrior do, a SW has a damage and a defense stance in the beginning, don't know if that's the case with BH but if so, set yourself to tank.  With Mako healing, you should be ok.
Also, check if the enemy is using powerful but slow attacks (you see that in the target info, if there's a casting bar going down) and interrupt them.

Comment: yeah... been using her since I got her. No stances that I am aware of.

Comment: another little tip then. Start the fight with Mako (click on her ability to attack). Wait a couple of seconds and then you attack. The idea is that the first round or 2 of the enemy go to the companion (hopefully he'll start with his big attacks), and since you'll get his attention anyway, that's a couple of shots you don't receive.

Comment: @Rodolfo That is good advice in many cases, but not in this case. After you draw aggo, Mako will heal herself and not contribute to the dps so nothing will be gained. Secondly, especially on the lower levels her dps is high so it might even be impossible to get aggro. Therefor, in the case of a BH and Mako, it is better to start the fight with a big nuke and tank yourself.